# Solving a differential equation with a $\ln$ function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''-2\ln(1-x)y'=x$

Hello, I am currently learning on this topic and got stuck on the following question. In order to solve it I attempted to do an order reduction $z = y'$

Then I obtain my equation

$z'-2\ln(1-x)z=x$

Unfortunately this is not separable and I ran out of ideas. I appreciate any help thank you.

Comment: Try integrating factors.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'll look into it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-2\ln(1-x)y'=x$$
You can try to solve the homogeneous equation:
$$y''-2\ln(1-x)y'=0$$
$$\frac {y''}{y'}=2\ln(1-x)$$
$$(\ln {y'})'=2\ln(1-x)$$
$$\ln {y'}=2 \int \ln(1-x)dx$$
Substitute : $$u=1-x \implies du=-dx$$
$$\ln {y'}=-2 \int \ln( u)du$$
$$\ln {y'}=-2 ( (1-x)\ln( 1-x)-(1-x)) +C_1$$
$$ {y'}=Ce^{-2 ( (1-x)\ln( 1-x)-(1-x))}$$
$$ {y'}=C(1-x)^{2 (x-1)}e^{2(1-x)}$$
Even the homogeneous equation is not easy.

Comment: I see thanks. I just solved it with order reduction and integrating factor. my final answer looked complicated as well.

Comment: @Josue  It's hard to solve.  Even the homogeneous equation is not simple here WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%27-2%5Cln%281-x%29z%3Dx